# How to create a loop in R to average ndvi raster time series?

Tags: r, loop, ndvi

I have monthly ndvi raster geotiffs for multiple years. I need to run a loop to get the average of each of these ndvi grids/rasters.

> Each of my ndvi rasters contains 143 pixels. I would like the mean of all the pixels within a raster across my time series.

Can someone offer any advice?

Comment: Do you want the global mean, moving window mean or mean of each pixel across your time series? Please be clear in your questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [cellstats](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/raster/html/cellStats.html) in the [raster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf) package to calculate a global mean for each of your raster layers.  To illustrate:

```
# Create some sample data
r1 <- matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)
x = raster(r1)
r2 <- matrix(rnorm(1000),20,20)
y = raster(r2)

# Calculate global mean in the multi-layer object
cellStats(brick(x, y), mean)
```

The results:

```
> cellStats(brick(x, y), mean)
    layer.1     layer.2 
0.001735036 0.047742064
```

---

The same thing, but this time in a `for` loop:

```
# Get a list of NDVI's
setwd("C:/temp_ndvi")
files = list.files(getwd(), pattern = "\\.tif$")  # Get only the .tif files

# Loop through files and print global mean for each raster
for (i in files) {
  j = cellStats(brick(i), mean)
  print(j)
}
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I have a raster list (made up of 671 raster objects) and I am hoping to create a loop through them all to calculate the sum of each of their pixels.